# How to define an empty parameter for minipage

Tags: macros, minipage, arguments, parameters

`minipage` supports  empty values for its optional arguments:

```
\begin{minipage}[c][][c]{1cm} test \end{minipage}
```

or

```
\begin{minipage}[c][\relax][c]{1cm} test \end{minipage}
```

but it doesn't if that empty values are passed by a macro:

```
\def\param{}
\begin{minipage}[c][\param][c]{1cm} test \end{minipage}
```

or

```
\def\param{\relax}
\begin{minipage}[c][\param][c]{1cm} test \end{minipage}
```

How can I properly define the macro, so that minipage takes an empty value?

Comment: With `\let\param\relax` rather than `\def\param\relax` (which is wrong: `\def` requires a braced definition, so you'd need `\def\param{\relax}`)

Comment: Are you sure? Try: `\let\param\relax
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\param][c]{1cm} test \end{minipage}}
\def\param{1cm}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\param][c]{1cm} test \end{minipage}}` (and with `\def\param{\relax}` you will get an error)

Comment: sorry @PhelypeOleinik, you're right. Yours may be the accepted answer.

Comment: egreg's answer says pretty much the same, you can accept his.  In short you need something that is `\ifx`-equal to `\relax`, and the way to get that is with `\let\param\relax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal code for `minipage` uses the optional arguments when processing `\endminipage`. At a certain point, `\@iiiparbox` is called, which does `\ifx\relax#2`, where `#2` is the second optional argument (or `\relax` if the optional argument is empty). Since no expansion is performed by `\ifx`, your code compares

```
\ifx\relax\param
```

which returns false, because `\param` is a macro expanding to `\relax`, not the same as `\relax` (assuming you gave `\def\param{\relax}`; or it expands to nothing, which again is not the same as being empty when the argument is absorbed if you give `\def\param{}`.

By the way, `\def\param\relax` is incorrect syntax; in the two lines in the second example you're defining `\param` with parameter text `\relax\begin`, expanding to `minipage`. But the intended `\def\param{\relax}` (that I assumed in the answer) will not work, as explained.